# Why MVC handler didn't execute after IAppBuilder.Run method invoked?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, katana

In MVC5, which integrated with OWIN(Katana) via Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll, why MVC handler didn't execute after [IAppBuilder.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.appbuilderuseextensions.run(v=vs.113).aspx#M:Owin.AppBuilderUseExtensions.Run(Owin.IAppBuilder,System.Func%7BMicrosoft.Owin.IOwinContext,System.Threading.Tasks.Task%7D)) method invoked, and did execute after [IAppBuilder.Use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.appbuilderuseextensions.use(v=vs.113).aspx#M:Owin.AppBuilderUseExtensions.Use(Owin.IAppBuilder,System.Func%7BMicrosoft.Owin.IOwinContext,System.Func%7BSystem.Threading.Tasks.Task%7D,System.Threading.Tasks.Task%7D)) method invoked?

Here are my implementations:

Case 1:

```
   public partial class Startup
   {
      public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
      {
        app.Use( async (context, next) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(@"<h1>Before MVC</h1>");

            await next.Invoke();  //What 's the "next" object now?

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(@"<h1>After MVC</h1>");
        });

      }
   }
```

Case 2:

```
    public partial class Startup
    {
      public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
      {
         app.Run( async context => 
         {
             await context.Response.WriteAsync(@"<h1>MVC has not been invoked.</h1>");
         });

      }
    }
```

In this case, as i know, OWIN component run as HttpModule(OwinHttpModule), which registered in Asp.NET pipeline.
So why Execution of IAppBuilder.Run method led to skipping of MVC module?

Answer (score 2):

You can find info about `Run` method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.appbuilderuseextensions.run(v=vs.113).aspx)

> Inserts into the OWIN pipeline a middleware which does not have a next
>   middleware reference

MVC handler executed after all owin middleware components (OMCs), that's why it skipped.`Use` method just add new module. MVC handler will run after all modules. `await next.Invoke` will wait for execution of the next OMC. Read [this](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline) articles.

Try experiment with this code

```
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {              
             context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, world.");
             return Task.FromResult(0);                         //case 1
            //return next.Invoke();                             //case 2   
        });
```

Case 1 will return only `hello world`

Case 2 will append `hello world`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Anton.And i had already read that article before.As you mentioned, "MVC handler executed after all owin middleware components (OMCs), that's why it skipped", that really over my head. **Because Case 2 above,  only contains one OMC apparently(the last OMC?).  It seems that MVC handler should run after this OMC,  but actually it didn't.** Did i miss anything?

Comment: It should run if only request will reach it (handler) going through all pipeline.If last module will not call next.Invoke handler will be out.See upcoming update.

Comment: you can treat mvc handler as OMC, in some case (if you play with self-host) it's really true. http://blog.2mas.xyz/asp-net-5-adding-mvc-to-an-application/

Comment: No, its not httpmodule. One of the Owin goals  was to decouple frameworks from host environment and make them pluggable.And IHttpModule is part of System.Web ."The major difference between this and the previous implementation of the HTTP pipeline is that the event-driven approach has been replaced with a composable model"